# Use JQuery to copy value from table to modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onclick, buttonclick

I have a **table** with a list of all my data. **The data is printed in a for loop so there are many rows in the table.** how can i get the userid in the row with the button clicked?

```
<table>
        <td>
            <input type="hidden" value="<c:out value="${user.id}" />" name="userId" />                          
        </td>
        <td>
        <button class="btn btn-default fileUpload" data-toggle="modal" id="btnUpload" data-target="#file-modal" value="<c:out value="${user.id}" />">Upload</button></td>
</table>
```

and i have a **modal** container. When the **upload button in the table is clicked**, the *modal* will open up for a file upload.

```
<form action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/UserServlet" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
                    <input type="hidden" value="5519" name="OPS" />
                    <input type="hidden" name="uploadUserId" />
                    <div class="form-group">
                        File : <input type="file" class="file" name="uploadFile"><br />
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Upload</button>
                        <br /><br />
                    </div>
                </form>
```

What i am trying to do is on the *click* of **btnUpload** the value in the *hidden* input type **userId** will be copied over to the *hidden* value type **uploadUserId**

I have tried doing the following but neither works

## 1

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#btnUpload").click(function(){
        var $userId = $(this).closest("tr").find("#userId").text();
        $("#uploadUserId").val($userId);
    }); 
});
```

## 2

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#btnUpload").click(function(){
            var $userId = $(this).closest("tr").children()[2].text();
            $("#uploadUserId").val($userId);
        }); 
});
```

Comment: Why don't you the id for hidden element and use that to get the value from hidden field

Comment: @Aravind i do not get what you're saying. can you be more specific?

Answer (score 0):

This will do the trick without changing the html

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#btnUpload").click(function(){
        var $userId = $(this).parent().prev("td").children("input:hidden").val();
        $("#uploadUserId").val($userId);
    }); 
});
```

Another solution by adding ID to the input element as shown below,

```
  <input id="userVal" type="hidden" value="<c:out value="${user.id}" />"name="userId" />
```

then you can get the value from the following jquery

```
   $("#userVal").val();
```

Comment: i forgot mention that the main table is running a for loop and the method using .parent().prev("td").chidlren.... it does not retrieve the ID where as the #userVAl.val() method gets only the first id. can you please help me?

Answer (score 0):

This should work. Just select and grab the user Id txt and then pass it to the uploadUserId value.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#btnUpload").click(function(){
        var $userId = $('#userId').text();
        //$("#uploadUserId").val($userId);
        $('input[name="uploadUserId"]').val($userId);
    }); 
});
```

**UPDATE**

OK. I reviewed this again using your HTML structure and got this all worked out. The code below works.

```
$('[type="submit"]').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); // prevents the button default action. You can remove this if you want the form to submit after click.
    var $userId = $(this).prev().prev().val(), // this gets the input value. based on your html it is the previous previous element.
        fix1 = $userId.replace(/(?:\..+)$/, '').split('\\'), // this is a regex that replces the file extention then splits the string on the back slash turning it into an array.
        fix2 = fix1.length -1; // gets the length of the array and subtracts 1 to get the last array index of the array. This i to get the file name.

    $('[name="uploadUserId"').val(fix1[fix2]); // this assigns the uploadUserId value to the name of the file using the  array and the index.
});
```

Comment: Sorry. I just caught what is id. We need to grab the hidden input by name not by id. Since the field dose not have an id.

Comment: but there are multiple rows with the #userId  filed as i am printing the data in a for loop. i tried this but it returns the wrong ID, how can i get the selected row's user ID?